# need concept to understand declaration of array in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog

I am always confusing while declaring an array and Array Querying Function in SystemVerilog. Can you explain me in details for given example:

**Example-1**

```
integer matrix[7:0][0:31][15:0];

// 3-dimensional unpacked array of integers i am confuse in size 
// and dimension of given array for 1 and 2 dimension its easy to 
// understand but for 3 and 4-dimension its little bit confusing...
```

**Example-2**

```
//bit [1:5][10:16] foo [21:27][31:38];
```

**Example-3**

```
//module array(); 

bit [1:5][10:16] foo1 [21:27][31:38],foo2 [31:27][33:38]; 

initial 

begin 

$display(" dimensions of foo1 is %d foo2 is %d",$dimensions(foo1),$dimensions(foo2) );

end
```

**Output ...**

```
dimensions of foo1 is 4 foo2 is 4
```

I am not getting this also...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Sec: 7.4.5 Multidimensional arrays of IEEE 1800-2009

The dimensions preceding the identifier set the packed dimensions.
The dimensions following the identifier set the unpacked dimensions.

```
bit [3:0] [7:0] joe [1:10]; // 10 elements of 4 8-bit bytes
```

In a multidimensional declaration, the dimensions declared following the type and before the name
(`[3:0][7:0]` in the preceding declaration) vary more rapidly than the dimensions following the name
(`[1:10]` in the preceding declaration).
When referenced, the packed dimensions (`[3:0], [7:0]`) follow
the unpacked dimensions (`[1:10]`).

i.e. In a list of dimensions, the **rightmost one varies most rapidly**, as in C.
However, a **packed dimension varies more rapidly than an unpacked one**.

```
bit [1:10] v1 [1:5]; // 1 to 10 varies most rapidly
bit v2 [1:5] [1:10]; // 1 to 10 varies most rapidly
bit [1:5] [1:10] v3 ; // 1 to 10 varies most rapidly
bit [1:5] [1:6] v4 [1:7] [1:8]; // 1 to 6 varies most rapidly, followed by 1 to 5, then 1 to 8 and then 1 to 7
```

**Example 1:** You can view the setup like this:

[image: Example 1 illustration]

**Example 2:**

```
bit [1:5][10:16] foo [21:27][31:38];
```

This is similar as example 1.

[image: Example 2 illustration]

**Example 3:**

```
module array(); 

bit [1:5][10:16] foo1 [21:27][31:38],foo2 [31:27][33:38]; 

initial 

begin 

$display(" dimensions of foo1 is %d foo2 is %d",$dimensions(foo1),$dimensions(foo2) );

end
```

The declaration in the above module is as same as

```
bit [1:5][10:16] foo1 [21:27][31:38];
bit [1:5][10:16] foo2 [31:27][33:38];
```

As Dave has mentioned, `$dimensions` function gives you the total number of dimensions packed and unpacked. Sice both foo1 and foo2 are 4 dimensional the displayed value is 4.

For more on this topic please go though the following link. This would clear your all doubts. A nice representation is provided here.
http://testbench.in/SV_09_ARRAYS.html

Comment: hello sir thanks for explaining but in example how each register of 32 bit,it might be 1 bit i think so???

Comment: Its 32 because matrix is defined as an multidimensional array of integer. integer is 32 bit (See what Dave has mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that may be confusing you.

From Verilog, the packed type is part of the *data type* of all the variables that follow

```
reg [7:0]  rega, regb, regc[0:9]; // rega, regb are 8-bit variables, regc is an unpacked array of 10 8-bit variables
```

SystemVerilog added multiple packed dimensions, but it is still part of the basic data type

```
reg [7:0][0:3]  rega, regb, regc[0:9]; // rega, regb are 32-bit variables, regc is an unpacked array of 10 32-bit variables
```

The $dimensions function gives you the total number of dimensions packed and unpacked, $unpacked_dimensions just gives you then number of unpacked dimensions.

`integer` is a shortcut for `reg [31:0]`, `int` is a shortcut for `bit [31:0]`. So

```
integer matrix[7:0][0:31][15:0];
```

is a 4-dimensional array with 1 packed dimension (also called a vector) and 3 unpacked dimensions.

Comment: //bit [1:5][10:16] foo [21:27][31:38];  so sir  for these i can say foo is unpacked 56 30-bit variable am i correct if i am wrong just tell where i am doing mistake

Comment: [1:5] is a range of 5, [10:16] is a range of 7. 5 * 7= 35 bits.

[21:27] is a range of 7, [31:38] is a range of 8. 7*8= 56 elements